# c# Filter datatable with multiple condition

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

fresh programmer here. I have a table named [dt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsLV.png) and i want to select

1. the latest datetime for **distinct** id in column 'Entity'
2. where their message/status = 'State'.

I searched that there is a method called LINQ and i tried write some code. How to select from the datatable with these requirement?

...

```
    DataTable filterDT = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Message/Status") == 'State')
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```

...

Answer (score 0):

```
 DataTable filterDT = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Message/Status") == 'State')
                        .DistinctBy(p => p.Entity)
                        .CopyToDataTable();
```